# Error duplicate case value inside switch in switch

Tags: c, switch-statement

I don't really know how to fix the issue since as far as I'm aware they're in two different switch cases. If anyone could either explain to me why this won't work or an alternative to switch cases that might work more efficiently it would be greatly appreciated

```
if (StudentDB == NULL){
    printf("The file does not exist. Would you like to create one?\nY/N\n");
    scanf(" %c", &d);
    switch (d){
        case 'Y':
        case 'y':
            {
            StudentDB = fopen ("studentdb.txt", "w");
            printf("A new file has been created\n");
            if (unsaved==1)
            {
                printf("Would you like to save your unsaved student files to this document\nY/N\n");
                scanf(" %c", &e);
                switch (e)
                case 'Y':
                case 'y':
                    unsaved = 0;
                    while (printing < student_no){
                        printing++;
                        printf("A");
                        fprintf(StudentDB,"%s %s\t%d\t%d %d %d/t%.2f\n",
                        arr_student[printing].fname, arr_student[printing].sname, arr_student[printing].UP_no, arr_student[printing].marks_1,
                        arr_student[printing].marks_2, arr_student[printing].marks_3, arr_student[printing].average_mark);
                        }
                    fclose(StudentDB);
                    printf("saved");
                    break;
                case 'N':
                case 'n':
                    break;
            }
        }
    case 'N':
    case 'n':
        printf("Returning to menu");
        delay(1);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: `switch (e)` - Where are the curly braces? You must have them to surround multiple statements. This is all essentially the result of a typo.

Comment: @UnslanderMonica That's it! Thank you so much! Sorry, I just completely missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the braces.For a single statement you may or may not put braces .But for multiple statements you must definitely put braces.
If you don't put braces then only the immediate line after the switch statement come under switch,the next line is not considered to be in switch.